# - 2 Log L vs. Deviance

Tags: regression, deviance

I have a question.

> Is it better to use deviance or - 2 Log L for the likelihood ratio test? Or are they basically the same thing?

SAS returns the "deviance" sometimes. But I just use the -2 Log L value for the likelihood ratio test (e.g. subtract the -2 Log L for two models to compare them). Is is that okay?

Answer (score 5):

They are the [same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29) other than any arbitrary scaling.